# Invoke event for FakeItEasy stub

Tags: .net, fakeiteasy

I inject a stub generated with FakeItEasy to my class. At some point my class subscribes to dependency's event. I want to invoke this event afterwards as part of my test method but it does not seem to work:

```
var restApiManager = A.Fake<IRestApiManager>(); //IRestApiManager has Connected event
var target = new ViewModel(restApiManager);

target.Connect(); //some private method subscribes to RestApiManager.Connected

restApiManager.Connected(); //obviously not working
```

Is there a way to invoke an event from a stub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event raising is covered in the [Raising events](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/raising-events/) topic in the FakeItEasy documentation.

You'll want to call something like this

```
restApiManager.Connected += Raise.With(arguments);
```

or some variant, depending on the arguments the event supplies to the listeners.

If you've defined the event using a custom delegate, then you will need to supply a typeparam:

```
restApiManager.Connected += Raise.With<CustomEventHandler>(arguments);
```